# init UIView with parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have UIView class that presents view that is created programaticly in a controller.

When creating (initing) the UIView I would like to transfer parameters from the UIViewController, so instance variables of the UIView can be initialized. I want it to happen before `awakeFromNib` is called. So in `awakeFromNib` I could use these parameters.

I guess I need to do it in `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder`, but how? It only receives the `aDecoder`

Something like this:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
         _instanceParameter = parameterFromController;
    }

    return self;
}


-(void)awakeFromNib{
    if (_instanceParameter)
         do logic
}
```

Comment: if you're creating your "`UIView`" programatically (in other words, via code), you won't be creating it in a storyboard or XIB and "`awakeFromNib`" won't be getting called.

Comment: haaaa... @MichaelDautermann is here.. Others don't need to bother about this question.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, I have a xib. And in the controller I do:
_myUIView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myUIView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you've subclassed "`UIView`" into something, let's call it "`LudaView`".

Expose a property for your parameters and when you load it from your xib file, you can set your parameters there.  In other words:

```
_myUIView = (LudaView *) [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myUIView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
if(_myUIView)
{
    _myUIView.parameters = parametersFromViewController;
}
```

You could also set a BOOL property or ivar within your "`LudaView`" and then when a drawing method is called for the first time, you can set stuff up.  E.G.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
   if(everythingSetUp == NO)
   {
      // do stuff with your parameters here
      everythingSetUp = YES;
   }
   // you shouldn't need to call [super drawRect: rect] here if 
   // subclassing directly from UIView, according to Apple docs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, at lot of things are a bit unclear. When you create your custom view, you can call a second init function. Something like this:

```
// In the UIViewController
NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView"
                                              owner:self
                                            options:nil];
CustomView *myView = [[nibs objectAtIndex:0] initWithParameter:myParameter];
[self.view addSubview:myView];
```

Then in your UIView class:

```
- (id) initWithParameter:(id)parameter
{
    _instanceParameter = parameter;
    // Do whatever initialization you need to
    ...
    return self;
}
```

Just do all of the initialization you need to in the initWithParameter method.

Comment: But is't loadNibNamed calls awakeFromNib. 
The bottom line is: I want to initialise instance variables and then update UI accordingly. What functions should I use?

Comment: You can update the UI in the custom `- (id) initWithParameter:(id)parameter` method, or you can do it in `viewDidLoad` and just call viewDidLoad in the init funciton.

Comment: viewDidLoad is UIVIewController function

Comment: Ah, right. You could do UI customization in `-layoutSubviews`

Comment: Yes, there are several ways to do what you're trying to do. If you're only setting properties, then that works very well.