# init UIView with custom parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm trying to pass data to a custom uiview when initing.
I followed the method outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261145/init-uiview-with-parameters).

My UIView

```
-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        [self initAudioPlayer];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)initAudioPlayer
{
    self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:self.fileURL error:nil];
    [self.player prepareToPlay];

}
```

My ViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.audioURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"audio4" withExtension:@"wav"];
    AudioControlsView *view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AudioControlView"
                                                 owner:self
                                                options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    if (view)
    {    
            view.fileURL = self.audioURL;
    }
 [self.view addSubview:view];

}
```

When I do it this fileURL is nil.

I can get it to work with:

```
- (void)setFileURL:(NSURL *)fileURL
{
    _fileURL = fileURL;
    self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:self.fileURL error:nil];
    [self.player prepareToPlay];
}
```

But I don't think that's the proper way.

Comment: As [Dave says](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35398952/2976878), the setter approach is correct. However one thing to note is you should make sure to stop the previous player (if there was one) before creating another in the setter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code you have now, `-initAudioPlayer` gets called before you set the fileURL.

I'd remove `-initAudioPlayer` and all of the init code. Your `-setFileURL:` accessor method is the correct approach.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought it wasn't the correct way of doing things.